# Maven project creation

Tags: maven

I have tried searching answer for my error message

> ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer
>   xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
>   was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted
>   until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are
>   forced.
>
> Original error: Could not transfer artifact
>   xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after
>   60000

Tried with some suggestion given too but my problem is not resolved.

Comment: Let me know what you are trying to do, hope you are trying to build a maven project and the dependency added to your project fails downloading?

Comment: i have created maven project, added all dependency in pom.xml but im getting above mentioned error

Comment: Looks like network issue. When your network connection is intermittent  this exception will be thrown. In case you are using Eclipse as IDE do a maven update which will update all the project dependencies.

Comment: i had done that many times . by adding jar file manually the problem is resolved . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a maven update, if that doesn't resolve then add the jar file manually into .m2 maven repository with the below command executed from the command prompt if your OS is Windows after downloading xml-apis.jar file.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile={Path}/filename.jar -DgroupId=xml-apis -DartifactId=xml-apis -Dversion=1.4.01 -Dpackaging=jar
```

and add the below dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```

Try cleaning and building the project will build successfully.

Comment: i have added the jar file manually and yes it worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely the first time you tried to build  with Maven your internet connection failed.

Maven caches failures by default, so even though now you might have restored your connection Maven doesn't try again until a day later (I think 24 hours is default).

However you can force Maven to try again by building with the -U parameter.  e.g.

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: im using windows 7 does this command work for me ? and its been more then 24hrs already . Im using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: It does work with Kepler, 
`right click on the project->Run As-> Maven Build...` Edit configuration window will prompt you to enter Goals enter 
    `mvn -U clean install`
click apply.